# Where is Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, device, monitor

I updated my Android Studio to latest version.
But I can't find where the Android Device Monitor is.
In prior version, it was located in Tool - Android - Android Device Monitor.
But, in the latest version, there isn't.
Could you let me know where it is?

Comment: I don't understand why this question received negative votes. I can't find it either since the update. SO is so weird. I see some dumb question get voted like skyrocket and something I really need gets down-voted for no reason sometimes. And most of time, so many haters and people who just want to blame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find it in Android SDK
../sdk/tools/monitor

Answer (score 2):

To run Android Device Monitor:

- Windows: C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\monitor
- Linux: sh //Android/Sdk/tools/monitor

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow this path to set up the device monitor

Windows: C:\Users \ (Your PC Name)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64